# Having an issue running an external program with arguments

Tags: asp.net, path, process.start

I do have a final issue to my project and I just can't see clear enought to find out what the hell is wrong here.

When I run my code with this, everything is just perfect:

```
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    With p.StartInfo
        .WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles") & "\rest_of_my_path\"
        .FileName = "ping"
        .Arguments = "192.168.0.24"
        .CreateNoWindow = True
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
    End With
    p.Start()
```

However, when I run this, it throughs an error during runtime and crashes on p.start()

```
Dim p As Process = New Process()
With p.StartInfo
    .WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ProgramFiles") & "\rest_of_my_path\"
    .FileName = "myextprogram.exe"
    .Arguments = "-n Unnamed -f file.abc"
    .CreateNoWindow = True
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .RedirectStandardError = True
End With
p.Start()
```

I tried adding spaces, quotation marks, just name it but ALWAYS getting an **Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation**.
I believe it's complaining about the path.

I'm almost sure it's simple but just cannot put my finger on it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: no one having an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found a fix...if anybody is interested...

Rather than having

```
.FileName = "myextprogram.exe"
.Arguments = "-n Unnamed -f file.abc"
```

I now have

```
.FileName = "cmd"
.Arguments = "myextprogram.exe -n Unnamed -f file.abc"
```

Everything is working as expected now.